# How do I index an ICollection<T> like they tell me to in this example?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying list items in my MVC view, following this example: [Model Binding to a List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/). I'm using MVC 5. There example says to do this:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="ViewPage<IList<Book>>" %>
<% for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { %>
    <%: Html.EditorFor(m => m[i]) %>
<% } %>
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.SubmissionTypesSelected.Count(); i++)
{
    Html.EditorFor(m => m.SubmissionTypesSelected[i]);
}
```

`SubmissionTypesSelected` is defined like this:

```
public ICollection<PTSubTypeSelected> SubmissionTypesSelected { get; set; }
```

I get this message:

> Cannot apply indexing to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'

Comment: Why don't you use a `foreach` instead?

Comment: In the example, you have `IList<X>`. In your code there's `ICollection<X>`. That's not the same. IList is indexable. ICollection is not. Also, what Yacoub said. Iterating 0..Count === foreach, and ICollection is "foreachable" (just as every IEnumerable is)

Comment: This is part of a larger issue. I have nested collections, and can't get the results from the inner most collection. I was trying to use the index method to see if I could fix the problem.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850921/how-to-handle-nested-collections-in-mvc-5

Comment: `ICollection` implements `IEnumerable`, so you have access to its `ToArray()` method if you absolutely need to use indexing. But `foreach` is the better approach normally.

Answer (score 1):

The error is kind of self-explanatory; you can't use indexing on an `ICollection{T}` because it is designed to be able to modify the contents of a collection of elements, not the order of them. Changing it to a `IList{T}` is a simple answer, as the example you've linked does.

MVC needs to have indexes added in HTML so it can figure out which property value goes with which item in a collection on postback. The `EditorFor` will do this for you if you pass it an `IEnumerable` of any kind directly. So you can just do this:

```
Html.EditorFor(m => m.SubmissionTypesSelected);
```

It will loop through each item, generate an index for you, and pass the individual item to your editor template.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do this:

```
var typesArray = Model.SubmissionTypesSelected.ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < typesArray.Length; i++)
{
    Html.EditorFor(m => typesArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Just trying to implement your solution directly, without getting into why you need to use indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CopyTo(Array, Int32)` and then continue to iterate as you would normally do with an array.