# How to handle nested collections in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using MVC 5 and I want to have an edit page that allows selection of items from a list, with options for each item selected. So I have a model like this:

```
public class TemplateEdit
{
    public Guid TemplateId {get; set;}
    public string TemplateName {get; set;}
    public ICollection<MyOption> Options {get; set;}
}

public class MyOption
{
    public Guid MyOptionId {get; set;}
    public Guid TemplateId {get; set;}
    public string OptionName {get; set;}
    public bool Selected {get; set;}
    public ICollection<SubOption> SubOptions {get; set;}
}

public class SubOption
{
    public Guid SubOptionId {get; set;}
    public Guid MyOptionId {get; set;}
    public string SubOptionName {get; set;}
    public bool Selected {get; set;}
}
```

Let's assume I have LINQ to get the data for this. Now I want to display it. I was hoping to use `Editor` templates.

In my `template-edit.cshtml` view I have something like this:

```
@model TemplateEdit
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TemplateId)
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    @Html.LabelForRequired(m => m.TemplateName, new {@class = "control-label"})
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TemplateName, new {@class = "form-control"})
</div>

<div class="col-md-12" style="overflow: auto; height: 350px;">
    @Html.Label("Options Selected")
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Options);
    </div>
</div>
```

In `MyOption.cshtml` EditorTemplate:

```
@model MyOption
<div class="optionable">

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyOptionId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TemplateId)

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Selected, new { @class = "form-control optionToggle" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OptionName, new { @class = "form-control" } )
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row options">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SubOptions);
    </div>
</div>
```

In my `SubOption.cshtml` EditorTemplate:

```
@model SubOption
<div class="optionable">

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SubOptionId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyOptionId)

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Selected, new { @class = "form-control optionToggle" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SubOptionName, new { @class = "form-control" } )
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I am having is that when I return the model, I am not getting the SubOption data.

*Note:*
All the examples I find are for MVC3 or earlier, and use an index method to iterate through the collection. I would try that, except I am using ICollection for the collections.

Comment: Is it correct that Options is returning properly, but SubOptions isn't? Also, can you share what @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SubOptionId) is actually rendering on the page? EditorTemplates should work here, as long as the proper name is being rendered on the page

Comment: Are you not getting any data at all, or are you just missing the `OptionName` and `SubOptionName` properties? When I tried this those were the only ones missing, which makes sense as they have no `HiddenFor`'s.

Comment: The code you have shown will work fine. What is the signature of the POST method

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the SubOption data is present in the collection?  Don't assume, verify.  Also, shouldn't that be `TemplateEdit.cshtml` rather than `template-edit.cshtml`?  Unless template-edit is the top level view.

Answer (score 2):

Check what your action looks like in your controller. If you're passing the viewmodel as the parameter it should include your 'SubOptions' collection.

i.e.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveData(MyViewModel model)
    {
    }
```

Comment: _ People please don't mod me down for that._ Why not? You know the rules. But you could just have made this an answer.

Comment: wasn't sure yet if this solved the OP's request so i didn't want to post it as an answer. thanks for editing my answer for me.

Answer (score -1):

Change the `SubOption.cshtml` to look like this:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SubOption>
@foreach(var option in Model)
{
    <div class="optionable">

       @Html.HiddenFor(m => option.SubOptionId)
       ...

    </div>
}
```

You're passing a collection to the EditorFor so your template should also work with a collection instead of a single item.

Comment: This actually isn't necessary. When a collection is passed into EditorFor() MVC is smart enough to render an EditorTemplate for each one. In fact, when looping this way, I've often seen the model binding fail when the model is posted back

Comment: Using a foreach is almost always the wrong solution and will not generate the proper naming.  Besides, it's unnecessary, as Loren mentions.

Comment: Hm, as far as I remember this approach worked for me when I was actively using MVC. Also it's accepted as a working solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20280559/3731444

However, I'm not a professional in the MVC so I may still be wrong. Could you please describe what are the problems with this approach?